# mootools formcheck plugin and jquery conflict

Tags: jquery, mootools, validation

I have mootools and jquery both on the page.But the mootools plugin (formcheck) doesn't work when the jquery is called on the page.
firebug gives this error in console:

```
this.form.getProperty is not a function at line 314 of formcheck.js
```

Here's the code of that line:

```
this.form.setProperty('action',
  this.options.submitAction || this.form.getProperty('action') || 'post');
```

I don't understand what the problem is.
Would you help me?

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar problem before and I fixed it by replacing the $ in the jQuery code to the word jQuery

For example:

```
$("div.menu").show();
```

will be:

```
jQuery("div.menu").show();
```

Answer (score 2):

If jQuery is the problem, try using the built-in feature named **noConflict()**.

You can call it like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then you can wrap your original $(...) code like this:

```
(function($) {

original $(...) code    

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

here's an answer from the mootools perspective as well.

probably further up, like inside your initialize method, you have something like:

```
this.form = $(element);
```

due to jquery not returning the actual element but a wrapped element in itself, it will fail as jquery does not have a `setProperty` method. replace all mentions of $() in the mootools class with document.id or put it inside a closure that implicitly sets it.

```
(function($) {

// class with reliance on $ here


})(document.id);
```

mootools has had a document.id fallback since version 1.2.2 or 1.2.3, can't remember. in fact, since that version, it won't redefine $ if already set and will only rely on document.id to work.

since you use setProperty in the class, it leads me to think you may be using mootools 1.1x - in which case, no fallback will be available and you're stuck with `noConflict` on the jquery side.